# Given a start and end date, how can I loop until I reach the end date?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a start_dt and an end_dt object that are of type datetime.

How can I loop from the start_dt, incrementing by 1 day each time until I reach the end date?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `upto` and `downto` methods on `Date` and `DateTime` objects:

```
start_dt = DateTime.parse('2018-01-01')
end_dt = DateTime.parse('2018-01-15')

start_dt.upto(end_dt) { |date| puts date }
2018-01-01T00:00:00+00:00
2018-01-02T00:00:00+00:00
2018-01-03T00:00:00+00:00
2018-01-04T00:00:00+00:00
2018-01-05T00:00:00+00:00
2018-01-06T00:00:00+00:00
2018-01-07T00:00:00+00:00
2018-01-08T00:00:00+00:00
2018-01-09T00:00:00+00:00
2018-01-10T00:00:00+00:00
2018-01-11T00:00:00+00:00
2018-01-12T00:00:00+00:00
2018-01-13T00:00:00+00:00
2018-01-14T00:00:00+00:00
2018-01-15T00:00:00+00:00


end_dt.downto(start_dt) { |date| puts date }
2018-01-15T00:00:00+00:00
2018-01-14T00:00:00+00:00
2018-01-13T00:00:00+00:00
2018-01-12T00:00:00+00:00
2018-01-11T00:00:00+00:00
2018-01-10T00:00:00+00:00
2018-01-09T00:00:00+00:00
2018-01-08T00:00:00+00:00
2018-01-07T00:00:00+00:00
2018-01-06T00:00:00+00:00
2018-01-05T00:00:00+00:00
2018-01-04T00:00:00+00:00
2018-01-03T00:00:00+00:00
2018-01-02T00:00:00+00:00
2018-01-01T00:00:00+00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
current_date = object.start_dt
end_date = object.end_dt

loop do
  ## do something

  ## (`:beginning_of_day` and `:end_of_day` may help you)
  current_date += 1.day
  break if current_date > end_date
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to the following

```
start_date = Time.now - 30.day
=> 2017-12-16 09:19:51 +gmt
end_date = Time.now
=> 2018-01-15 09:19:44 +gmt

start_date = Date.parse "#{start_date}"
end_date = Date.parse "#{end_date}"

date_count = (end_date - start_date).to_i
=> 30

<% (1..date_count).each do |i| %>
  #Code to display using <%= i %> that you want to display    
<% end %>
```

Hope to help

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

```
(DateTime.parse('2018-01-01')..DateTime.parse('2018-01-15')).each do |date|

  puts date

end
```